# How can I have a smooth rendering?

Tags: modeling

I would like to obtain a realistic rendering with edges not too sharp and smooth surface. I tried adding a crease of 1, but edges are too sharp. Marking edges sharp is too soft. It seems there are some artifacts in the rounded corners...what can I do?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: are you talking about the pink edges or the blue edges?

Comment: About the indent shape (with the sharp edges marked in blue)

Comment: Smooth shading?

Comment: you can select loop and bevel by "CTRL+B". With size and profile (press P) you can control sharpness better than using crease. It is almost the same as add support edges.

Comment: I tried and bevel works perfectly here but I don't understand what you mean by "with size and profile (press P)". When I hit P the panel 'separate' appears.